# Spring boot login with email password

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I was developing a backend with spring boot for the first time. I chose email password login over username password login which is the default behavior of spring boot.

I have two objects: `AppUser` and `User`. `AppUser` is used for authentication and `User` holds every other data necessary for the application.

`AppUser`:

```
public class AppUser implements UserDetails {
    @Autowired
    AuthRepository repository;

    @Id
    private String id;
    @NonNull
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    @Field(value = "email")
    String email;
    @NonNull
    @Field(value = "password")
    String password;
    @Field(value = "authorities")
    private List<Role> authorities;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> auth = new HashSet<>();
        authorities.forEach(index -> auth.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(String.valueOf(index.getRole()))));
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

AuthController looks like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/Auth")
public class AuthController {

    Logger logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthController.class);

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    AuthService authService;

    @Autowired
    TokenGenerator tokenGenerator;

    @Autowired
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jwtRefreshTokenAuthProvider")
    JwtAuthenticationProvider refreshTokenAuthProvider;

    @PostMapping("/SignUp")
    public ResponseEntity signup(@RequestBody SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {
        logger.info(signUpRequest.getUsername());

        User user = new User(
                signUpRequest.getEmail(),
                signUpRequest.getPassword(),
                signUpRequest.getUsername(),
                signUpRequest.getFirstName(),
                signUpRequest.getLastName(),
                signUpRequest.getCountry(),
                null,
                false,
                false
        );

        AppUser appUser = new AppUser(
                signUpRequest.getEmail(),
                signUpRequest.getPassword()
        );
        boolean alreadyExists = authService.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail());
        if(alreadyExists){
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("Email Already Exists");
        }else{
            userDetailsManager.createUser(appUser);
            User newUser = userService.addUser(user);
            Authentication authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.authenticated(appUser, signUpRequest.getPassword(), Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(tokenGenerator.signup(authentication, newUser));
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/SignIn")
    public ResponseEntity signin(@RequestBody SignInRequest signInRequest) {
        logger.info(signInRequest.getEmail());
        logger.info(signInRequest.getPassword());
        Authentication authentication = daoAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(signInRequest.getEmail(), signInRequest.getPassword()));
        logger.info(authentication.getCredentials().toString());
        User user = new User();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(tokenGenerator.signin(authentication, user));
    }
}
```

The issue is with signin. SignUp works fine when I am providing email and password. Login is not working.

I am quite new so have zero idea where the issue is happening. Any reference code with explanation will help a lot.

[Github Link](https://github.com/fahimhoque/Igorox)

N.B: using spring boot, mongodb, oauth2

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding based on your WebSecurity.class, your are using OAuth2 authentication.
[image: As below image]

What I would do is create 2 Configurations inside the same class with a different Order and in the second one a custom AuthenticationProvider. This was Spring will try to authenticate first based on the first class and then on the second one

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration  {


    //here we set as the first in order the below config if this fails the next one in order will be used until any of them succeeds
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class MySecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Autowired
        private MyLoginRequestFilter myLoginRequestFilter ;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
            http
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/Auth/*").permitAll()
                    .addFilterBefore(myLoginRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class )
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .httpBasic()
            .and()
                .cors()
            .disable()
                .csrf()
            .disable()
            ;
        }

    }
```

Then insert your class below with  Order 2 and then close the whole file/class

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    @Slf4j
    @Order(2)
    //this is your class that is uploaded in the git. We actually encapsulate inside a generic Security Config class
    public class WebSecurity {
         @Autowired
         JwtToUserConverter jwtToUserConverter;
         ...
    }
} //to close the java class that was started in the previous block of code
```

You could even add a new function that will handle the HttpSecurity item so that you dont duplicate your code:

```
public HttpSecurity myHandler(HttpSecurity http) {
    return http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/Auth/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/Home/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors().disable()
;
}
```

Note that in the Order(1) example, I have added a filter, but you can leave it without a filter and add a custom AuthenticationProvider with inside the class:

```
    @Autowired
    private YourAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
```

YourAuthenticationProvider  could look like

```
@Component
public class YourAuthenticationProvider  implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    AuthService authService; //need to move here the authenticate method from the controller         Authentication authentication = daoAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(signInRequest.getEmail(), signInRequest.getPassword()));

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        final String email = authentication.getName();
        final Object credentials = authentication.getCredentials();
        
        if ( credentials == null ) {
            return authentication;
        }
        //I suggest using a password encoder to save the password and then check it with PasswordEncoder (you could create a bean)
        final Authentication auth = authService.authenticate(email, credentials.toString());
        if (auth  != null) {
            return auth;
        }
        throw new BadCredentialsException( "Wrong username and/or password" );
    }
}
```

Hope these help

Comment: isn't web security configurer adapter deprecated? Should we be using something like that?

Comment: Depends on what Spring boot version you use. What I sent is for 2.2 but you can use the same methodology for any newer versions and adapt it to your needs. My aim was to give you an alternative/way that you can use Beans and set them in @Order for you to handle multiple cases. I will try to clone your project and run it, even try to make customizations on it so I can give you a full example, provided I have some free time

Comment: That would be very helpful thank you. In the meantime I will keep learning more about spring security